# Embedded response undefined in openAI API

Tags: javascript, openai-api

I am trying to get the vectors from my embedded response after calling the openAPI API. I am getting undefined. Perhaps it is how i am trying to access the embedded response, or else it something in my JS code.

The error i am getting is: TypeError: undefined is not iterable

`const documents = [
"Cooper codes is a youtuber with 5,300 subscribers",
"Cooper codes likes clam choder",
"Cooper codes has a video ",
"Cooper codes has a web site called coopercodes.com"
];

```
for(const document of documents) {
    const input = document.replace(/\n/g, '');

    const parameters= {
        model: 'text-embedding-ada-002',
        input
    }

    const embeddingResponse = await openai.embeddings.create(parameters);

    const [{ embedding }] = embeddingResponse.data.data;

    console.log('Result:', embeddingResponse);

   // await supabaseClient.from('documents').insert({
    //    content: document,
    //    embedding
   // })
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

To access the vector in the embedding response the syntax i found that worked was:

```html
const embedding = embeddingResponse.data[0]['embedding'];
```